# Why does my OAuth2 won't working with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I'm trying to setup Facebook login with OAuth2 for Spring Boot.

First I have my spring security configuration. I want every page from www.localhost:8080/Intranet/** to become blocked for people that haven't been authorized by Facebook.

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
                .antMatcher("/Intranet/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/Intranet")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();
    }

}
```

I create my `application.yml` here:

```
  spring:
   application:
    name: spektrakonhemsida
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          facebook:
            clientId: myID
            clientSecret: mySecret
            accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
            userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
            tokenName: oauth_token
            authenticationScheme: query
            clientAuthenticationScheme: form
            resource:
              userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me
# Server configuration
server:
  port: 8080
  error:
    whitelabel:
       enabled: false
```

Then I have my dependencies for Spring Security and OAuth2:

```
        <dependency>


<groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Prevent /error to crash -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This is what's happening:

1. When I access www.localhost:8080/Intranet <- Works perfekt!
2. When I access www.localhost:8080/Intranet/Bokning <- I will be navigated to /error where my text shows up "You have no rights here! Please login".

But I want users to become automatically navigated to Facebook's login page when they enters /Intranet/**

Why does this not happening?

Comment: `spring.security.oauth2.client` is the valid prefix for OAuth2ClientProperties. Yours is `security.oauth2.client`

Comment: @SergVasylchak Where?

Comment: In `application.yml`

Comment: @SergVasylchak I have booth application.properties file too. It's for MySQL. Do you think that file can disturbe the yml file?

Comment: I have never had both of `application.properties` and `application.yml` so I cannot be sure.

Comment: @SergVasylchak I removed it. Anyway, I have updated my question. Still does not work.

Comment: are you sure about that upper case I in `Intranet`? Do you have controller/endpoint which matches the case?

Comment: @bilak i have read your question. Will answer it in 9-12 hours. Stan tuned.

Comment: @bilak The blocking working, but I am not able to become navigated too Facebook login page.

Comment: I have updated my question now.

Comment: hmm try to upload application to github or somewhere to look at it. it's difficult to know what's happening.

Comment: @bilak I solved the problem. Look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution now. This need to be done to make it work with Facebook.

Security:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/Intranet/Bokning").authenticated() // Block this 
        .antMatchers("/**", "/Intranet**").permitAll() // Allow this for all
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
        .and()
        .oauth2Login();
    }
}
```

And appllication.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
           facebook:
              clientId: myID
              clientSecret: mySecret
              accessTokenUri: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
              userAuthorizationUri: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth
              tokenName: oauth_token
              authenticationScheme: query
              clientAuthenticationScheme: form
              resource:
                 userInfoUri: https://graph.facebook.com/me

server:
  port: 8080
```

And pom.xml file:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```